# Set overlay over browser window using browser view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm working on a task that requires to put an overlay over an existing browser window that displays an app. The purpose of the overlay would be to draw some circles on it at specific points where in the application loaded via browser window there are some objects placed (basically the overlay just highlights those objects and gives the option of removal).

My challenge is how to load that overlay and how it should look: i imagine it would be a react component that i'm able to load somehow (i haven't figured out this part yet) in the browser view. The idea would be to have access to the objects placed on the application via ipc communication.

I saw that browser view loads an url but i'm not sure how to load a react component in it (or even if it's possible to do that).

Another challenge is how to display the overlay after the app was loaded (by using set bounds and set background color i saw that the browser view was displayed and after that the application loads and is placed on top of the browser view content).

If you can suggest other ways i can achieve this overlay effect, i'm open to suggestions, any idea/advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a mix of loadUrl and preload js combination: i'm loading a basic html file with a div that has an id and i specify for the browser view in web preferences to load a js file where i manipulate that html and create objects that will populate it with an event listener for click.

Comment: I'm interested to understand how to do that

Comment: @Raphael10 it's been a long time since I did that, unfortunately now I can't remember exactly how I did it. I'm sorry I cannot be of more use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Why don't you create a new transparent browser window and overlay it over your current window. Share the overlay component data between the windows via ipc.

Or if you can, share the data running a local server in your electron app over http. I always find this relatively easy as you don't have to send messages all the time to sync data. But this has it's cons too.

Comment: What would happen when i have 3 apps running, each with their own transparent browser window ? How will i keep count of which overlay communicates with each browser window ?